# When i have typed in this code nothing happens?

Tags: python

```
def print_menu():
    print('1. Print phone numbers')
    print('2. Add a phone number')
    print('3. Remove a phone number')
    print('4. Lookup a phone number')
    print('5. Quit')
    print()
```

I type in this code and nothing happens it just shows nothing. I dont really know whats wrong with the code, can someone help please!!!

Comment: Did you call `print_menu()` function?

Comment: You have told Python how to print a menu. You have not told it to do so.

Comment: indentation is very important.

Comment: Do you ever call print_menu()? Also, I'm guessing you aren't actually indenting your code as above. If you want all of those print statements to be part of print_menu(), they'll need to be indented.

Comment: Yeah there indented on the actual code however stack overflow didn't read it for some reason

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> def print_menu():
...     print('1. Print phone numbers')
...     print('2. Add a phone number')
...     print('3. Remove a phone number')
...     print('4. Lookup a phone number')
...     print('5. Quit')
...     print()
... 
>>> print_menu()
1. Print phone numbers
2. Add a phone number
3. Remove a phone number
4. Lookup a phone number
5. Quit
()
```